# An unintentional white line at the top of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

So my problem is that I have a white line on top of the layout when I'm running the code on an Emulator which cannot be seen on the blueprint nor the preview. [That's the emulator's screen (and the white line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5MpH.png) Here is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="#fe9f0f"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Budapest"
            android:textColor="#fbf6f0"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fef7e1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines of code to your onCreate method to hide your status bar

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  < 16){
    getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}else{
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```